# How to write :hover using inline style?

Tags: html, css

```
     <a href="#">Alink</a>
```

All i need is while i hover the color should change for the link, But it should be completely using only inline CSS

*No Scripting or external CSS

Please help me out in this.

Comment: i think you can achieve it. in html add <style> a{
font-weight:30px;
color:#000;
}
a:hover{
font-weight:30px;
color:yellow;
}</style> something like this

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not gonna happen with CSS only

Inline javascript

```
<a href='index.html' 
    onmouseover='this.style.textDecoration="none"' 
    onmouseout='this.style.textDecoration="underline"'>
    Click Me
</a>
```

---

In a [working draft of the CSS2 spe](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515#pseudo-rules)c it was declared that you could use pseudo-classes inline like this:

```
<a href="http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS"
   style="{color: blue; background: white}  /* a+=0 b+=0 c+=0 */
      :visited {color: green}           /* a+=0 b+=1 c+=0 */
      :hover {background: yellow}       /* a+=0 b+=1 c+=0 */
      :visited:hover {color: purple}    /* a+=0 b+=2 c+=0 */
     ">
</a>
```

but it was never implemented in the release of the spec as far as I know.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css-style-attr-20020515#pseudo-rules