# I want to use hover on my button. The button is in my php code

Tags: php, css

I tried to make a `class` but it didn't work so I tried in `style` to make it `hover` but it doesn't work as well. How can I make the background color of the `button` change when I hover. Or how can I make a `class` in php?

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['uID'])) {
            echo "<form action='includes/logout.inc.php' >
                    <button>LOG OUT </button>
                </form>";
            } else {
                echo" <form action='includes/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
                    <input type='text' name='u_Email' placeholder='E-mail'> <br/>
                    <input type='password' name='uWachtwoord' placeholder='Wachtwoord'> 
            <button style='background-color:orange;color:white;border-width:0px;width:300px;height:50px;font-family:BerlinSansFB;font-size:30px;hover:background-color:black;' name='button' id='button' type='submit'>LOGIN</button>
                </form>";
            } ?>
```

Comment: Read up on [CSS hover states](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905033/how-to-use-hover-in-css)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293280/css-pseudo-classes-with-inline-styles or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376496/how-to-write-hover-using-inline-style.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write :hover using inline style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376496/how-to-write-hover-using-inline-style)

Answer (score 2):

Try this with internal css.

```
    <style> 
.button1 {
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

Give this class to your button and try it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Move all those styles into a separate CSS file, and then use the `:hover` pseudo-class, like this:

```
button {
  /* All those styles */
}

button:hover {
    /* Stuff you want to override on hover. For example: */
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have changed your code : add class name "login-button" for button

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['uID'])) {
            echo "<form action='includes/logout.inc.php' >
                    <button>LOG OUT </button>
                </form>";
            } else {
                echo" <form action='includes/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
                    <input type='text' name='u_Email' placeholder='E-mail'> <br/>
                    <input type='password' name='uWachtwoord' placeholder='Wachtwoord'> 
            <button class='login-button' name='button' id='button' type='submit'>LOGIN</button>
                </form>";
            } ?>
```

Put CSS :

```
.login-button { background-color:orange;color:white;border-width:0px;width:300px;height:50px;font-family:BerlinSansFB;font-size:30px; }
.login-button:hover { background-color:black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a `button:hover {}` css styling that is separate from `button {}` styling.

It is better to separate the css from html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style media="screen">
            button {
              background-color:orange;
              color:white;
              border-width:0px;
              width:300px;
              height:50px;
              font-family:BerlinSansFB;
              font-size:30px;
            }
            button:hover {
              background-color:black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if ( isset($_SESSION['uID']) ): ?>
            <form action='includes/logout.inc.php' >
                <button>LOG OUT </button>
            </form>
        <?php else: ?>
            <form action='includes/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
                <input type='text' name='u_Email' placeholder='E-mail'> <br/>
                <input type='password' name='uWachtwoord' placeholder='Wachtwoord'>
                <button name='button' id='button' type='submit'>LOGIN</button>
            </form>
        <?php endif ?>
    </body>
</html>
```