# How to edit a div hover using html only?

Tags: html

I'm looking for a way to edit a div hover using only html. I need it to be html only because the code allows for an infinite number of different versions of the same div that are all different colors. I know with regular divs, you can include **style="color: red"** but that only lets me edit the original div.  I need a code that will allow me to do so for the hover only.

TLDR: I want to be able to edit the circle:hover in html. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 32px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px 15px 30px 15px;
    transition: height 0.5s ease;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.circle:hover {
    border-radius: 32px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    height: 200px;
    transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

#text {
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-top: 115px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle" style="background: rgba(197,214,210,1); box-shadow: 
0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(197,214,210,0.4);"><div id="text">#C5D6D2</div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a:hover in inline CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376496/how-to-write-hover-using-inline-style.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work (put this in your css)

```
.circle:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Edit: Since you don't want to use css, you can create an id for that circle and then apply it there.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I don't want to use css.  CSS would make it so that every circle has a red background.  I wanted to use HTML because then the user could make each circle a different color of their choosing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cant do a inline style for a *hoover* because it is a CSS pseudoelement and you only can access via Style Sheet.

What you can do is add inline javascript in order to change the styles

```
<div class=circle href='index.html' 
    onmouseover='this.style.color="red"' 
    onmouseout='this.style.color="black"'>
</div>
```

The best practice is to link a CSS StyleSheet in the section and work it from there.
You can do it adding the following HTML tag:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="ThePath/ToYour/CssFile.css">
</head>
```

Other option is to add a 
    
tag and write down your hover style there.
In this case you will end with a HTML like This:

```
<head>
    <meta lots of meta data>
</head>

<body>
 <p class="circle"> this is the element yo want to style </p>
</body>

<footer>
    <style>
       .circle:hover {color: red}
    </style>
</footer>
```

I do not recomend you to do this, is neither the best nor for the clarity of the code, nor the SEO, etc.

Also, as it aswered word by word in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033166/11280510)

> You can add links to external stylesheets if that's an option. For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var link = document.createElement("link");
  link.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
  link.setAttribute("href","http://wherever.com/yourstylesheet.css");
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
  head.appendChild(link);
</script>
```

> Caution: the above assumes there is a head section.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the hover color with a [custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) in the `style` attribute, then reference it in a `:hover` ruleset in the stylesheet. The same technique can clean up your `background` and `box-shadow` declarations:

```css
.circle:hover {
  color: var(--hover-color);
}

.circle {
  background-color: rgba(var(--bg-color), 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(var(--bg-color), 0.4);
}

/* your original CSS */

.circle {
    border-radius: 32px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px 15px 30px 15px;
    transition: height 0.5s ease;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.circle:hover {
    border-radius: 32px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    height: 200px;
    transition: height 0.5s ease;
}

#text {
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-top: 115px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle" style="--hover-color: red; --bg-color: 197, 214, 210"><div id="text">#C5D6D2</div>   
</div>
```